# how to add css on date-picker from mui

Tags: css

[i am trying to make width of expiary same as other component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJ3AK.png)

i have tried every things for the styles but it didnt work

Example:
inputProps={{ style: { width: "100%" } }} ,

style={{ width: "100% !important" }} ,

```
          InputProps={{
                    style: {
                      width: "100%",
```